# why twitter for android don't use background service?

Tags: android, twitter, service, notifications

I have used twitter for android app in my android device, and this app sometime notify me for new tweet, but in the running app there's no service of this app.

Why twitter for android don't use a service for its tweet push notification?
What is the technology used by twitter for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the technology used by twitter for this?

[Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), most likely.

Comment: Does GCM need background service?

Comment: @AkhmadGhozien: Not a continously-running one. Depending upon the work to be done when a message arrives, you may want an `IntentService` to do a bit of work that will take more than a few milliseconds. But an `IntentService` automatically shuts down when that work is complete, so you may not notice it.

Comment: But Whatapps and Facebook app have service who run continously and never shutdown?

Comment: @AkhmadGhozien: You are welcome to get jobs with those firms and then ask their respective development teams why they do what they do. In general, continuously-running services is an anti-pattern in Android. However, their brands are big enough that some people will put up with such sub-standard behavior.